# What is the one dimensional analog of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem and the Euler characteristic?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

The Gauss-Bonnet theorem has to do with surfaces. Its generalization has to do with $2n$ ($n$ being an integer) manifilolds.
Is there an analog in one dimension with closed curves?
If there exists one such analog, then what is the geometrical interpretation of the analog of the Euler characteristic?

Comment: The [total curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_curvature) of a simple closed curve in the plane is $2\pi$. The Gaussian curvature $K$ can be interpreted as the Jacobian of the [Gauss map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_map). In certain sense, $\int K dA$ is computing the area of unit sphere (using the Gauss map as parameterization) and hence equals to $4\pi$ (for surfaces w/o holes)